# Selected option value is empty while posting the data in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-select for select dropdown. I got the selected option value in onchange. While submitting the data on the signup form, the selected option value is always empty. How to get the selected option value in form handle submit submit like name and password.

```
  class addAtribute extends Component {

        handleFormSubmit({ name, password,role }) {

              this.props.signup({ name, password, role});
       }

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={value:''};
   // this.state={};
  }


render(){

    const { handleSubmit, fields: {name, password,role }} = this.props;

    return(
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
            <div className="login" id="login" >
                <div className="col-md-12"> 
                   <input  placeholder="Password" id="pwd" className="login-password form-control" type="password" {...password} />
               <label for="dropdown-custom-1" >Select the Role</label>
                <Select value={this.state.value} options={options} 
                         onChange={event =>                                                                                                       this.setState({value:event.value})} {...role} />       </div>

                                            <button action="submit " className="btn btn-block"><div action="submit" className="login-submit ">Update</div></button>

    );}}


    var options = [
      { value: '1', label: 'Admin'},
      { value: '2', label: 'Manager' },
      { value: '3', label: 'Editor' }];


      function mapStateToProps(state){
           return {auth: state.auth}
      }

       function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
           return bindActionCreators({ signup }, dispatch);
       }


         export default reduxForm({
               form: 'signup',
              fields: ['name', 'password','role'},mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(addAtribute);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
```